# Routing migration from ASP.NET WebAPI to ASP.NET Core WebAPI, ambiguous method issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-routing

I have existing ASP.NET WebAPI which I want to migrate to ASP.NET Core WebAPI, but facing some issues in routing.

The APIs are already consumed by many clients and I cannot change the routes (or URLs). We have a controller (say ValuesController) with 2 Get methods but different parameters:

`public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get(int xId, int yId)`

`public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get(int xId, int yId, int aId, int bId)`

In current scenario (ASP.NET WebAPI), all the clients are able to call both methods on the basis of different parameters like:

For calling method first, one can request to URL:
`http://localhost:4040/api/Values?xId=1&yId=2` and for second one, you can request to URL: `http://localhost:4040/api/Values?xId=1&yId=2&aId=3&bId=4`. And it get automatically decided by the current routing available with ASP.NET WebAPI

But in case of ASP.NET Core, if I request to the same URL, it throws the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched` exception.

Any possible solution without changing the request call for every client application?

Answer (score 0):

if is possible then why doont you make it a single function??
this is the way i think without disturbing other code
i.e

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get(int xId, int yId, int aId=0, int bId = 0)
{
if(aID>0 && bId>0)
{
//Your second controller code here 
return your result
}
else
{
//Your second controller code here 
return your result
}
}
```

now both the calls can be handled in same function

Comment: Thanks for your response... yeah... this is what I have already implemented as a work around. I was just looking if there is something available in ASP.NET Core WebAPI same as what we have in ASP.NET WebAPI. Like any package or something, which can help in Action Selection on the basis of number of parameters... I am not sure why this feature is not in Core..